# Help connecting OpenVPN in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: openvpn

I'm new in Ubuntu and would like to know if there exist a complete step by step tutorial on how to set up an OpenVPN connection. I am hoping that it would be as easy as doing it in Windows 7. I have .ovpn files that I want to use. Are there any packages that I require? Is there an existing GUI for connecting to OpenVPN or am I expected to go through the terminal and be knowledgeable about certain commands? I hope you can help me out! :)

Answer (score 9):

You can use the Network Manager applet to configure VPN connections. You need to install the openvpn plugin first.

Either from the command-line:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

Or through the software center (search for network-manager-openvpn-gnome).

Then, your network applet menu will let you configure VPN connections. It will have an additional "VPN Connections" menu, with a submenu to "Configure VPN...". From there, you can import your existing .ovpn file, enter the location of your key and certificate files, enter the key password, etc.

Depending on your vpn server configuration and your needs, you may also want to:

- define special DNS servers ?
- check "Use this connection only for resources on it's network" ?
- etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are excellent resources available, read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNClient) and [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenVPN).

For a gui client you could try `GOpenVPN` or `hamachi` or `gvpnc`. Look for these in the software center.

Comment: Thanks for the links. As I have mentioned in my query though, I'm a beginner in all things Ubuntu and linux and have little experience in navigating the Terminal. I was hoping that there would be an OpenVPN GUI which will let you run .ovpn files to connect the VPN. I guess it won't be that easy.

Comment: UPDATE: GOpenVPN does not work for me, I dunno why. It does say in the homepage that it's only for Ubuntu Jaunty (9.04?) and mine's 12.04. I don't know why it's not working. I was able to put the .opvpn files under etc/openvpn as instructed but when I run it, it does not appear anywhere. The other ones I haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 1):

hey you can install OPEN VPN plugin by going to networks and select Openvpn then install OPEN VPN plugin

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Link is broken now.